# altering DISPLAY for existing "child" window

Tags: linux

I am working within the RedHat7 environment.  For esoteric reasons, I have 2 VNC sessions open.  The first session is myMachine:51.  The second session is on myMachine:52.  I launch my main software on VNC session myMachine:51 and the graphical interface pops up as expected.  I then invoke a child process from within this main software package and a new independent child window pops up (also on myMachine:51).

I use the linux command "xwininfo" and obtain the window ID for the child window as "0xa00022".

Now comes my question:  Is there a way that I can change the DISPLAY variable for this new child window after the fact so that I can move it to myMachine:52 while keeping the parent window (with a different ID) still my original maching (myMachine:51)?   I have searched every page of documentation that I can find and have been scouring the internet for days without luck.  Please keep in mind that this is for the RedHat7 environment.

Any tips would be appreciated.
Thanks, Shawn

Comment: I suppose you could span another process, passing it the DISPLAY environment variable. I don't know whether a single process can use two different displays, but two process surely can.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.  But, let me clarify.  I don't need to have the child process use two separate displays.  I am actually trying to reassign the DISPLAY variable for spawned child process window.  If you could clarify how to reassign a DISPLAY setting for an existing window, I would be grateful.

Comment: I think that DISPLAY is read only once by the dynamic library, when the application starts. Or, at least, this is how 99% of program works. Modifying it for a running program has no effect, unless the program itself contains some special code to manage this case. You could study the X dynamic library, but I doubt it contains features to move an established window from a server to another.

Comment: ...moreover... you can *not* alter the environment (where the DISPLAY variable resides) of another process. Simply, there is no such functionality in linux.

Comment: Thanks.  Sadly, I have been coming to that conclusion as I search and search and keep coming up empty.  I was just hoping that I was wrong.  This seems really weird that an operating system as powerful as unix/linux cannot do something like moving a terminal window from one display to another.  I appreciate your inputs.  (shawn)